# How to create a Summary() Function from scratch?

Tags: r

I want to make a Defined User Function which is pretty similar to the summary(), just to practice, but it gives me error message. Does anyone can help me?

```
quick_view < - function (df) {
    n == 0
    while (n <= 1) {
        quantile < -quantile(df, n)
        n < -n + 0.25
        if (n == 0) {
            sprintf("Min: %s", quantile)
        } elseif(n == 0.25){
            sprintf("1Q: %s", quantile)
        } elseif(n == 0.5){
            sprintf("2Q: %s", quantile)
        } elseif(n == 0.75){
            sprintf("3Q: %s", quantile)
        }else {
            sprintf("Max: %s", quantile)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: first you need a space between else and if, second you don't declare n in the beginning of the function you need to use `n <- 0` (or =), thirdly you are not returning the result. Fix those issues then see what else goes wrong and fix / update your question with that and what kind of error message you get.

Comment: quick_view<- function(df){
  n<-0
  while (n<=1){
    quantile<-quantile(df,n)
    if (n==0){
      paste0("Min: ", quantile)
      n<-n+0.25
    }else if(n==0.25){
      sprintf( "1Q: %s",quantile)
      n<-n+0.25
    }else if(n==0.5){
      sprintf("2Q: %s",quantile)
      n<-n+0.25
    }else if(n==0.75){
      sprintf("3Q: %s",quantile)
      n<-n+0.25
    }else{
      sprintf("Max: %s",quantile)
      n<-n+0.25
    }
  }
}

Comment: when i call a vector in this function still not printing the expected summary statistics

Comment: you need to add print around your `sprintf` calls. Also never name variables the same as functions, like your quantile. Any issues just edit your question.

Comment: yeah mate tks, i found the same, now i am just strugling when the N==0 it doesnt print the quantile value

Comment: quick_view<- function(df){
n<-0
while (n<=1){
quantile<-quantile(df,n)
if (n==0){
  print("Min:",quantile)
  n<-n+0.25
}else if(n==0.25){
  print(sprintf( "1Q: %s",quantile))
  n<-n+0.25
}else if(n==0.5){
  print(sprintf("2Q: %s",quantile))
  n<-n+0.25
}else if(n==0.75){
  print(sprintf("3Q: %s",quantile))
  n<-n+0.25
}else{
  print(sprintf("Max: %s",quantile))
  n<-n+0.25
}
}
}

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. No need for putting `n <- n + 0.25` in every while statement. Just at the end is good enough.

```
quick_view<- function(df){
  n <- 0
  while (n<=1){
    quantiles <- quantile(df,n)

    if (n==0){
      print(sprintf("Min: %s", quantiles))
    } else if(n==0.25){
      print(sprintf("1Q: %s",quantiles))
    } else if(n==0.5){
      print(sprintf("2Q: %s",quantiles))
    } else if(n==0.75){
      print(sprintf("3Q: %s",quantiles))
    } else{
      print(sprintf("Max: %s",quantiles))
    }
    n <- n + 0.25
  } 
}

quick_view(1:10)
[1] "Min: 1"
[1] "1Q: 3.25"
[1] "2Q: 5.5"
[1] "3Q: 7.75"
[1] "Max: 10"
```